# returning a view versus a copy warning

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I am trying to create a new column that checks if there's a string in my values using the following method:

```
 user['validacao_LP']=user['MEDIA_SOURCE'].str.contains('LP')
```

But I keep getting the following message:

```
<ipython-input-27-841ac3ae43d8>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  user['validacao_LP']=user['MEDIA_SOURCE'].str.contains('LP')
```

I have already tried to use the lines bellow aftwer reading the documentation but I keep getting the same message.

```
user.loc[:,'validacao_LP']=user.loc[:,'MEDIA_SOURCE'].str.contains('LP')
user['validacao_LP']=user.loc[:,'MEDIA_SOURCE'].str.contains('LP')
user.loc[:,'validacao_LP']=user['MEDIA_SOURCE'].str.contains('LP')
```

Comment: did you check out [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/10197418)?

Comment: Looks like the dataframe `user` is itself already a copy of another dataframe, hence pandas says that `user['validacao_LP']` is a slice of a copy, which you can't assign to. **Show us the code that defines `user`.**

Comment: That was it, I had a line above defining user as a copy a previous user df. 
Corrected it and it worked. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dataframe `user` is itself already a copy of another dataframe, hence pandas warns that `user['validacao_LP']` is a [slice of a copy, which you can't assign to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).

Check the code that defines `user`.